# OSMNX animation networks

Tags: animation

I have a network graph plotted using OSMNX package on python, and I would like to make an animation of traveling through the network. Is there a package I can use in Python to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

As OSMnx is a street network analysis package with some static visualization functionality, this question would appear to be about how to work with animation in Python generally. Good places to start include:

- [matplotlib's animation API](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html)
- [plotly's animations](https://plot.ly/python/animations/)

Or consider using OSMnx to produce snapshots of your route traversal, one step at a time, then assemble them into an animated GIF, similar to the process described [here](http://geoffboeing.com/2015/04/animated-3d-plots-python/).